# node imap attempting to update flags: Error: Command received in Invalid state.

Tags: node.js, exchange-server, imap

Submitting this question and its answer because SA (and for that matter Google) was VERY unhelpful about this.

I need to delete all messages in my INBOX. Irrelevant lines below cut for clarity:

```
function openInbox(cb){
    imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);
}

imap.once('ready', function() {
    openInbox(function(err,box){
        if (err) throw err;
        var f = imap.seq.fetch('1:*', {
            bodies: 'HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)',
            struct: true
        });
        f.on('message', function(msg, seqno){
            console.log('Message #%d', seqno);

            imap.seq.addFlags(seqno, 'Deleted', function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });

        });
        f.once('end', function(){
            imap.end();
        });
    });
});

imap.connect();
```

It all looks good, when I pepper it with console.log, I see that it's reading emails just fine. Everything looks like it ought to be good, but I get:

```
{ [Error: Command received in Invalid state.] textCode: undefined, source: 'protocol' }
```

Comment: If you're trying to mark messages as deleted, the flag is named \Deleted (or \\Deleted with escaping).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you've opened the INBOX in read-only mode. That's the 'true' in the second argument right here:

```
function openInbox(cb){
    imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);
}
```

Change that to

```
function openInbox(cb){
    imap.openBox('INBOX', false, cb);
}
```

And suddenly it'll all work.

Answer (score 0):

**Read To UnRead in IMAP FLOW Code**

```
client.messageFlagsAdd({uid: 116,seen: false}, ['\\Seen']);

client.messageFlagsRemove({uid: 116,seen: true}, ['\\Seen']);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.